# Is there any way to sign-in (login) users programmatically in Azure API Manager developer portal?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

There is an API to create users that can access the developer portal, but AFAIK there is no API to login users programmatically.

If I want to develop a totally custom developer portal (a separate web application on another host) and this is the only feature I lack.

I know I can switch to Active Directory authentication, but I wonder if I can login users directly created by the API manager (into its own database).

Comment: This might be possible as of recently.  I am checking with the dev involved.  I can assure you it currently isn't documented :-)

Comment: Are there any news on this feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/User/GenerateSsoUrl to get a Sign-In Url with a valid Token.

Powershell Cmdlet here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/Get-AzureRmApiManagementUserSsoUrl?view=azurermps-4.4.1

Comment: may you please elaborate more ? how I'm supposed to login a user from a custom login form ?

Comment: yes, I think I understand your question now, but we need to discuss the implication and risks involved. Please reach out to us on https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. We are currently doing it in a production environment (FantasyData.com). I believe they call it delegation, because you're delegating the login functionality to another website that you host. It's a little tricky to setup the redirects to work just perfectly, but once done, it works like a charm.

Here are the online docs for it, it's just a REST API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/azure-api-management-rest-api-user-entity#SSO

Comment: Ok but I don't want to have a separate database for users, I want to login users against the API manager "embedded" user database.

Comment: OK got it. Our situation was different because we had built up a large user database over the year before integrating with azure API management.

Comment: So, what do you want to do exactly and why do you want to do it? Usually the existing login functionality is fine, unless you have a separate user db. Why do you want to implement a custom login against the azure user database?

Comment: I'm trying to make a complete separate website to use it as a developer portal. I don't want to handle users account myself; I want to reuse the account management facilities provided by the API manager developer portal. I can have a sign-up form (because you can create users programmatically through API) but I cannot have a sing-in form because you cannot login these created users programmatically.

Comment: OK. If you want to create a custom developer portal without your own database, then you would probably need to use the Azure API Management API to manipulate users, products, apis, operations, etc. Best of luck!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/